# Discovery of iOS devices connected to Mac OS X machine

Tags: ios, macos, discovery

Is there any way to programatically discover iOS devices connected to Mac OS X machine. Either by system command or some Obj-C Library function? I'd like to upload developer signed app to device without using XCode. Is that even possible?
Thanks

Comment: Nope, as far as I know! Apple is very strict regarding these things :)

Comment: Well, there probably is some way. Take a look at AppCode from JetBrains. They discover my iPad and they even run the app on the device, ... but how?

Comment: [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/) also discovers devices and even accesses the filesystem.